# MySQL nested queries with UPDATE and SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one has a reference to the other. I want to do the following:

```
UPDATE candidate_skill SET skill_id = skill.id WHERE skill_id = SELECT 

WHERE skill.name = "name" ;
```

Is my syntax correct? How can I do the same with join?

Comment: _is my syntax correct?_ - Try it.

Comment: in your query, `skill_id = SELECT` but select what?

Comment: Definitly it is not correct.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You query is incorrect. Can you explain in words what it is meant to do?

Comment: I think what you want is this UPDATE candidate_skill SET skill_id = (SELECT id FROM skill WHERE name = "name"); not sure if this will work not so good in sql ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to determine exactly what you are trying to do based on your query, but it appears that you are trying to update some set of rows in the `candidate_skill` table to set the `skill_id` value to the id of a given `skill` based on name.

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this. With either example, you should provide the proper where clause for the `update` statement to define which rows are updated.

One way is to use a sub-query:

```
update candidate_skill 
set skill_id = (select id from skill where name = "name")
where ...;
```

Another solution is to use a user-defined variable:

```
select id 
into @skill_id
from skill 
where name = "name";

update candidate_skill 
set skill_id = @skill_id
where ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a correct syntax. Your query should look something like below

```
UPDATE candidate_skill a 
    JOIN skill b ON a.skill_id = b.name 
SET a.skill_id = b.id
```